# Is [in]frequency countable or uncountable?

Tags: grammar

> Going to the dentist once a year is not enough

Now, which one would describe `once a year` better, `too few` or `too little`?

### Update

I know the expression is complete, but it was just an example to ask a more general question:

If I wanted to refer to a frequency (once a year), should I consider that as countable or uncountable?

Comment: I think the missing word is 'times'.
>Going to the dentist once a year is not enough [times]
times for what is unanswered tho..

Comment: @kztd My challenge is not to change the example, is to refer to "once a year". In my example, is "once a year", beside "not enough", "too few" or "too little" or neither? Maybe "too few times"?

Comment: Going to the dentist once a year is too low a frequency (_NOT_ 'too low of a frequency'). Going three times a day is probably too high a frequency.

Comment: "Few" refers to a number. "Little" refers to a quantity. "Once a year" is neither -- it's a *frequency*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is needed in that sentence. "Not enough" is complete as it is, though it could be "not often enough".
You could say that "once a year is too little", with this meaning:
[Merriam-Webster *little*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/little)
(adverb)  2 rarely, infrequently
I'm not sure if that should be called a predicate adverb, but I think it is idiomatic.

"Too few* doesn't work at all, because "few" is an adjective and doesn't have anything to connect to in your example.

Frequency can be represented by real numbers, such as 1.25 times per second or per year, so it isn't countable. If you stick to whole numbers, you can make a sentence where frequency refers to specific occurrences, such as "5 instances/times/occurrences per year". Then you can refer to each instance. In that case, the instances are countable, though the frequency itself isn't.

However, if you are referring to a set of frequencies as discrete, individual things, then those could be countable.

Comment: By `not needed`, do you mean they don't work?

Comment: I know the expression is complete, but it was just an example to ask a more general question: "If I wanted to refer to a frequency, should I consider that as countable or uncountable?"

Comment: @reith  I've changed my answer to address "too little" and "too few" directly. This isn't so much a question of the countability of frequency.

Comment: Thanks. Can't I use "too few times"? I found some similar results using ngram.

Comment: Yes, but it would be awkward and wordy, given all the shorter, more idiomatic expressions, like "not enough".

Comment: I didn't completely understand your judgement of countablity and whole numbes.. I think I can say `I ate half a pizza` and pizza is countable.

Comment: Yes, pizza pies can be countable. Halves of pizzas are countable too. You should probably think of countability as a property of a usage, rather than as an invariable property of a noun. If I say I have 25 pounds of pizza, that is not a countable use; we are not referring to individual pounds there.